# Modification of a flash object

Tags: php, flash, zlib, swfobject

I was looking to proxy access to embedded videos from a particular website. The reason for this is not to violate their TOS, but only so that I can serve their content on an HTTPS site.

I was able to decompress and recompress the swf object with the following code:

```
$input = file_get_contents("/tmp/swf.swf");
$header = substr($input, 0, 8);
$header_old = $header;
$data = substr($input, 8);
$header[0] = "F";
$data = gzuncompress($data);
//$data = str_replace('http://.../','https://localhost/',$data);

$data2 = $header_old.gzcompress($data);
file_put_contents($tmp."2.swf",$data2);
```

When I view their swf file on localhost, I receive a normal looking error message and the same also if I run the code with the commented line.

If I uncomment the replace function, then the swf object behaves in an abnormal way. I also try without recompressing the output, and the result is similar.

Could this be because there is some kind of a checksum in the swf object?

Comment: Maybe you should post the error message or explain what "abnormal behaviour" is

Comment: Flash does not give "errors". The error message that I mentioned is normal behavior ("cannot load video" - because of the cross domain policy).

At the least, all I am asking is about checksums.

Comment: I was referring to "I receive a normal looking error message" and "the swf object behaves in an abnormal way"